# What is the game where you strike a stack of discs to knock one out?

Tags: nichijou

There was a game that appeared in a few episodes of **Nichijou** (not familiar with the original manga) where there was a bunch of circular (wooden?) discs stacked and a small hammer was used to try to strike one out, and I assume the object is to do so without toppling the stack.

[image]

Was this a made up game for the series or is it a real game? What is it called?

Comment: i believe it was not a game ment to knock the other out !!! :P you just have to knock out one of the discs till the head reaches bottoms. if it falls you lose

Comment: @Dimitrimx I know you're not supposed to hit the other person with the block (was the only screenshot I could find), by "knock one out", I mean knock it off the stack.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The game is called [Daruma Otoshi<sup>en.wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daruma_doll#Children.27s_games) ([だるま落とし<sup>ja.wikipedia</sup>](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8B%E3%81%BE#.E3.81.A0.E3.82.8B.E3.81.BE.E8.90.BD.E3.81.A8.E3.81.97))

Let me quote Japanese Wikipedia, since the text on English Wikipedia might be inaccurate at the time of writing of this post.

> 弾丸の先端に形状が似ただるまの下に、薄い円柱を数段重ね、それを横から1段ずつ木槌で叩いて抜き、倒れないようにうまく一番上のだるまを落とすという玩具・遊びである。胴を素早くたたくのがコツである。

Rough translation (I'd appreciate it if someone can edit it with a better translation):

> (Skipped text) Under the daruma head are several thin cylinder pieces stacked on top of each other. The game involves hitting the thin cylinder pieces from the side with a mallet one by one, bringing down the daruma head without the rest toppling over. The trick is to hit the body quickly.

Image retrieved from Wikipedia at [File:Darumaotoshi.JPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Darumaotoshi.JPG)

[image]